# How to provide column titles in Python

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am saving arrays `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` in four separate columns in a CSV file. However, I don't know how to add column titles. The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np
import csv 

A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B=np.array([[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]])
C=np.array([[21,22,23],[24,25,26],[27,28,29]])
D=np.array([[31,32,33],[34,35,36],[37,38,39]])

with open('Data.csv', 'w') as f:
        print(A)      
        print(B)  #for pressure
        print(C)  #for velocity
        print(D)
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(zip([A],[B],[C],[D]))
```

The current output is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qwdQ.png)

The desired output is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZmYh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add an additional `writerow()` to add the header row. Also, you need add `newline=''` in the `open` statement, so that an additional newline is not added. Updated code below...

```
import numpy as np
import csv 

A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B=np.array([[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]])
C=np.array([[21,22,23],[24,25,26],[27,28,29]])
D=np.array([[31,32,33],[34,35,36],[37,38,39]])

with open('Data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        print(A)      
        print(B)  #for pressure
        print(C)  #for velocity
        print(D)
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        myheaders = list('ABCD')
        writer.writerow(myheaders)
        writer.writerows(zip([A],[B],[C],[D]))
```

**Output**

[image]